# Narrow down possible types in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I am trying to write a function, that based on the presence of an object property in the input parameter object, returns various types. My original problem would be rather large to be put here, but I managed to create a simpler example, which demonstrates my problem. Consider the following code:

```
interface variousTypes {
    a: string;
    b: number;
}

interface always {
    neededAlways: any;
}

interface optional<TAttributes> extends always {
    optional?: keyof TAttributes | boolean;
}

declare function test<T extends variousTypes, O extends optional<T>, K extends keyof T>(options: O): 
    O extends { optional: boolean } ? 'extends-boolean' : 
    O extends { optional: K } ? T[K] :
    'base-type';

const a = test({
    neededAlways: 'test',
    optional: 'a'
}); // a has type of "string | number" instead of "string" only

const b = test({
    neededAlways: 'test',
    optional: 'b'
}); // b has type of "string | number" instead of "number" only

const c = test({
    neededAlways: 'test'
}); // c is correctly typed as 'base-type';

const d = test({
    neededAlways: 'test',
    optional: true
}); // d is correctly typed as 'extends-boolean' type
```

Basically, what I would like, that given the `test` function and various input parameters, the `a` and `b` variables should be narrowed down to `string` or `number` respectively, instead of the `string | number` typed.

I also made a fiddle on the TS playground: [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgG5ysA9gVwM4AqAngA4R7IDeAUMncnAFzJ5iYgDmA3LfQEbMQOALZ9oPAL7VqoSLEQo4AGwDucIhRr1kICBAAmBgIKr1eZnBBFJ02dHhJkWEmGwhlAHgJGwbYHxxIPAA%20ZAgAD0gQfQplNQ0qXjpnVyx3JQB%20ZgBrCCIsGGRvX0wAoOQAH2Q%20LCwlCEsbakMEJQwUGBwQBFSQZCCwLzDIiGiKdExcQlJyABpkAHlhqJinFzdPAmD5gGll0dXc-MKtgAoUt3NFgEpmJMX9sao13uVmGrqGvolkDOQAcgiKzwAFoPvVLP9kHdtEsgQdNC8NkpmHsfn8CABtHYAXWh93%20fDgeAgILAM3%20PGoCDSrAYyAAvP1yGBTlp6LoDMZTBpmP8Bv9ZvcLmk3gC4P9qBJrlxkAB6OX0gAWxP6MychQARKx2BxKjoRGIoJrkKBWA19BrkNq-JwTWklERpDSQHS%20Izmaw2fdOYZ9CZ4ld%20SzBcL1qKUQC%20JLpbKFdVkCqKOSyFabbr9UJRNATWbIHBLQVrVmjfaQI7nbSwMgEB6Bt7tL7uYG%20QKpTL5Yra8AKDSoFAID1HWqyJbVYTiaSUxBKZXXdXLUz6%20y6E3-TygwKhdoRelmGwcBB23HFZaezWsP3B2Bh9OxxRASMxmDahCQFDp0A)

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/WJRnRW) meet your needs?  There basically wasn't a good inference site for `T` or `K` in your original example.  There's a great inference site for `O`, though, since `options` is of type `O`, so you can use that and calculate the others.  If it meets your needs I can probably write up an answer; if not, please elaborate about unsatisfied use cases.

Comment: Yes, that did the trick!

Comment: Okay I will write up an answer but probably not until after I get some sleep.